# "What is wrong with the following listing?" I'm trying to learn functions but need some assistance

Tags: c, function

```
#include <stdio.h>
void printMessage(void);
int main()
{
   printMessage("I know my stuff!");
   //leave console window on screen
   printf("\n\nPress ENTER to continue...");
   getchar();
   //return from main routine
   return(0);
} //end main
void printMessage(void)
{
   printf("I know my stuff!");
   //return from function
   return;
}
```

So we got this code as an example and were told to figure out what is wrong with it. Visual Studios underlines `printMessage("I know my stuff!");` as the part with the mistake but I don't know what's wrong. Any assistance would be helpful for someone just learning code.

Comment: `printMessage` doesn't take any arguments, and you are trying to pass an argument to `printMessage`.

Comment: `void printMessage(void);` say "There is no argument.". It is expected to be called as `printMessage();`.

Comment: functions, code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) groups of `#include` statements, groups of function prototypes, should be separated via a blank line, for readability

Answer (score 3):

The printMessage() function is declared to take no parameters, but the call passes a pointer to char, i.e., the string literal "I know my stuff!" to the function.

It is very simple to change the code so that it works ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
void printMessage(char message []) /* You can also use void printMessage(char *message) */
{
    printf("%s\n",message);
    return;
}
```

or

```
void printMessage()
{
    printf("I know my stuff!\n");
    return;
}
```

If you use the first method, you should also change the function declaration at the top (line 2) to be `void printMessage(char message []);`.
If you use the second one, don't put anything in the parentheses when you call the function (at line 5)